# How to Write Protect a external card (sd card and pen drive)

Tags: java, android

The videos in my SD card needs to be protected so that no one can Copy/Paste or Delete the files.
I want to write protect a external card in android (sd card and pen drive). but not found any method after googling. Please Help !!

Comment: what is `write protect`?

Comment: it means files are only in readable format. no one can copy the files from that sd card

Comment: ok, why you think that it is read-only? Which exactly external sd card are you talking about? it it the removable microSD card? Which version of Android are you talking about?

Comment: All the things cannot discuss here. Can you please share me your Skype ID or any other? @VladMatvienko

Comment: no, sorry, only here.If you can't discuss it here, then you won't get the answer.

Comment: The main issue is to protect video files in my sd card . which no one can copy and delete videos?

Comment: sorry, you didn't answer my questions.

Comment: sir it is removable sd card ,android version 5,6.

Comment: ok, for removable SD card, starting from Android 4.4 there is no easy way to write there. You have to use `StorageAccessFramework`. And now - what you want: do you want to secure your files, so they can only be read, not written/removed, right?

Comment: Yes sir only read.

Comment: you can't make it, and there should be no way to do that since user should be able to remove any files from SD card any time he wants. And you shouldn't be able to stop him from doing it.

Comment: Thanks sir for your answere.